# Get the selected text from WebView in android. Text is selected using CAB in 4.0 and above

Tags: android, android-webview

Hi I am working on a project in which user can select text on an web view by long press on the text and as he made selection I want to get the text and speak out that text using tts. Please some body help me. I had tried a lot but could not get success. I also tried using javascript code provided on stackoverflow. This code is returning undefined.

```
{var txt = '';"
+ "     if (window.getSelection){"
+ "        txt = window.getSelection();" 
+       "}else if (document.getSelection){"
+ "        txt = document.getSelection();" 
+ "      }else if (document.selection){"
+ "        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;" 
+        "}"
+ "  android.selectedText(txt);"; 
}
```

If any body got the solution please reply soon.